# When I change the orientation of the device, there is a small black flash on the screen, Flutter

Tags: flutter, flash, screen, orientation

I have a sin up page that works very well, but when I switch to landscape mode, there is a small black flash on the screen that also disappears very early. flutter

I created a sign up page on flutter but when I switch from portrait to landscape mode, I see a black square appear on the screen before it disappears

When change the device orientation (by rotate the device) an black screen is painted in the bounds

what are the cases that can cause this?

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. It is not clear what you are talking about. Someone will down vote you if you don't do so.

Comment: I feel like the class stateful recreate instead of reusing the widget

Comment: No one has ever had this problem, how to solve it

Comment: @ThamuMnyulwa, you're gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share my solution which is quite easy compared to my question above. Maybe it will save someone's time.
the black edge that appears when the device pivots (see image) disappeared during the execution of a release (flutter run apk --release).
suddenly everything is going well.